# Convert a tab seperated array to a list in bash

Tags: bash

I have a tap separated array file which looks like

```
12479 12499 12518 12540 12557 12578 12585 12597 12608 12627 12634
```

I want to get something like

```
12479 
12499 
12518 
12540 
12557 
12578 
12585 
12597 
12608 
12627 
12634 
12646
```

My try:

```
while read line; do echo $line; done < file.dat

while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a file.dat; do  echo myArray; done < file.dat
```

I believe I am missing some simple syntax or maybe there is a better way to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Expand the file inside `()` to make it an array. By default any whitespace will be used as the word delimiter.

```
myArray=($(cat file.dat))
printf '%s\n' "${myArray[@]}"
```

You can also use the `tr` command to convert tabs to newlines:

```
tr '\t' '\n' < file.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case since the values do not contain white space we can get away with a `for` loop, eg:

```
$ for f in $(cat file.dat); do echo $f; done
12479
12499
12518
12540
12557
12578
12585
12597
12608
12627
12634
```

One `awk` idea:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file.dat
12479
12499
12518
12540
12557
12578
12585
12597
12608
12627
12634
```

Answer (score 1):

With the builtin `read` and `IFS`

```
IFS=$'\t' read -ra array < file.txt; printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

Bash4+ with `mapfile` aka `readarray`

```
mapfile -d $'\t' -t array < file.txt; printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

---

Or `awk`

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='\n' file.txt
```

---

Or `sed`

```
sed 's/\t/\n/g' file.txt
```

---

Or with GNU `grep`

```
grep -Eo '[^[:space:]]+' file.txt
```